# Prevent matlab from memory allocation when using chol

Tags: matlab, memory

I want to compute the cholesky decomposition of a 50000 by 50000 matrix. This is currently implemented as

```
A = chol(A, 'lower');
```

As you can see, the symmetric matrix `A` is replaced by the cholesky factor. However, matlab briefly allocates twice the amount of data needed to store `A`.

On a desktop system I can just set the swap to 32 GiB. This will resolve the out of memory error. On my HPC cluster most nodes offer 32GiB of memory and 4GiB of swap. In theory, this is sufficient, but in practice the unnecessary memory allocation performed by matlab results into a out of memory error.

I know that the LAPACK routine `dpstrf` (also used by matlab) does not need to allocate additional memory. My question is: Do I have to reimplement my code in C or fortran or is there some other solution?